# Using reCAPTCHA on a PHP form

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I would really apreciate if you could help me.

I have a form that ends with this button:

```
<button type="submit" value="Create" name="new">Create</button>
```

And then PHP process it using:

```
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] == "Create")
```

So I'm trying to add reCAPTCHA to it and I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php'); // reCAPTCHA Library
$pubkey = ""; // Public API Key
$privkey = ""; // Private API Key

if ($_POST['doVerify']) {
  $verify = recaptcha_check_answer($privkey, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);
  if ($verify->is_valid) {
    # Enter Success Code
     //process form
  }
  else {
    # Enter Failure Code
    echo "You did not enter the correct words.  Please try again.";
  }
}
?>
```

But I have no idea how to link them.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Put `if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] == "Create")` right after `//process form`?

Comment: What do you mean by "link them"? Link them in what way?

Comment: @Otome I mean, when the captcha is validated, process the form. But I can't do it the way Sean suggest because of the way the code is written.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php'); // reCAPTCHA Library
$pubkey = ""; // Public API Key
$privkey = ""; // Private API Key

if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] == "Create") {
  if ($_POST['doVerify']) {
    $verify = recaptcha_check_answer($privkey, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);
    if ($verify->is_valid) {
      # Enter Success Code
      //process form
    }
    else {
      # Enter Failure Code
      echo "You did not enter the correct words.  Please try again.";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Not much point validating the CAPTCHA if the rest of the form doesn't pass validation, right?

Answer (score 0):

let your filename of your "php piece of code" be `"capt.php"`

change the action of the form to `"capt.php"`

> eg:  `action =`"capt.php"

Enjoy!